eww filter html content before rendering based on website
after eww fetching the html content, I want to manually change the content before rendering, so I can read specific website more friendly. how to achieve that?
[Sovled]
thx for suggestion from @NickD
but I find a better portal to implement this: eww--preprocess-html
(defun my-eww-preprocess-html (start end)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region start end)
      (goto-char start)

      ;; (print (buffer-substring start end))
      (replace-regexp-in-region "<title>.*</title>"
                "<title> hello world </title>"
                (point-min) (point-max))
      ))
  )


(advice-add 'eww--preprocess-html
        :after 'my-eww-preprocess-html)
                                         
)

this even comes before libxml to parse the html.
sweet.

You can modify eww-display-html to filter the HTML stored in the document variable, before it calls eww-display-document. That's the (relatively) easy part. Writing (and debugging) the filtering function will be much more complicated (and since you don't describe what king of filtering you want to do, it's impossible to say anything more about it).

thx, I will try to dig eww-display-html for a bit. as for the filter part, I dont wanna design a general filter, but filters based on the website url, you know, ignore some doms, or ignore some results, etc.

If you have an example, then add it to your question with as many details as possible. Somebody might have some helpful ideas...

In principle it's much better to process the structured DOM data (i.e. after libxml parsing) than to use regular expressions to process HTML text (as regular expressions famously aren't capable of doing that generally due to the nested structures).

that portal is eww--parse-html-region,  in fact I tried to inject some advice first there, but it seems the whole eww design doesnot allow me to fetch and modify the html temp buffer at that time.

interesting, eww--parse-html-region seemed to be byte-compiled so advice not working but eww--preprocess-html works..

"... seemed to be byte-compiled so advice not working" - that's not correct: you can advise any function, whether it's byte compiled or not.
